# Convert blender2.79 code to blender2.8: game sensors

Tags: python, blender

I have some python code for `blender2.79` that uses game sensors. Recently, I updated to `blender2.8` and I need to run the same code with this version. However, the game engine and with it the sensors have been removed in `blender2.8`.
What should I use instead of sensors to get the same functionality with `blender2.8`?

This is for python 3.6.

```
bpy.ops.logic.sensor_add(type='DELAY', name='MySensor')
bpy.ops.logic.controller_add(type='LOGIC_AND', name='MyController')
bpy.ops.logic.actuator_add(type='MOTION', name='MyActuator')       

sensor = bpy.context.active_object.game.sensors['MySensor']
controller = bpy.context.active_object.game.controllers['MyController']
actuator = bpy.context.active_object.game.actuators['MyActuator']
sensor.duration = 1
sensor.delay = delay
actuator.force = force
actuator.angular_velocity = angular_velocity
actuator.use_local_angular_velocity = True
controller.link(sensor=sensor, actuator=actuator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, the game engine has been removed from blender 2.80, there is no replacement within blender.

Your first option is to have both 2.79 and 2.80 installed and continue using 2.79 for your existing game engine projects.

You could try asking at [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com), explaining what you want the game engine to do, to see if the end result can be achieved without it.

If you need an interactive solution, then you need to find a replacement for blenders game engine, have a look at [Godot](https://godotengine.org), [Unity](https://unity.com) and [UE4](https://www.unrealengine.com) as available options.

Comment: I cannot use a different tool but I also do not need an interactive solution. I am running a python script that uses blender for a physical simulation and then to render some images. I need this script to run on blender 2.8 because 2.79 won't let me select the GPU as a device. So at the moment the script is run on the CPU which is too slow. Blender2.8 does recognize my graphics card. I will try to achieve the same result on the cycles engine.

Comment: In older versions of blender we used the game engine for physics, recording the physics to keyframes, that is no longer needed. You can use the simulations by "playing" the scene, just increase the end frame to make the time long enough for what you need.